# How to use an expression which is based on time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button in my app, I only want it to be visible at night.

The javascript code:

```
$scope.isNight = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    return now.getHours() < 6 || now.getHours() > 22;
};
```

And the html:

```
<button ng-show="isNight()">Visible at night</button>
```

How can I make the expression be reevaluated when needed? Or is there a better approach for expressions depending on time?

Comment: Set a timeout to run every hour on the hour, on page load, calculate minutes until the next top of the hour, then after that, every hour.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an interval (preferably inside a directive) to check the time and set the visibility but you could also use a filter that is evaluated in every digest cycle.

```
app.directive('hideMeAtNight', function($interval) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      $interval(function() {
        var now = new Date();
        element.toggleClass('ng-hide', now.getHours() < 6 || now.getHours() > 22);
      }, 1000)
    }
  };
});

app.filter('nightFilter', function() {
  return function() {
    var now = new Date();
    return now.getHours() < 6 || now.getHours() > 22;
  }
});
```

And you can use them like:

```
<button hide-me-at-night>This is a button</button>
<button ng-hide="true|nightFilter">This is a button</button>
```

Demonstrated at this plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/tjAVWf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
var checkForNight = function() {
  var now = new Date();
  if (now.getHours() < 6 || now.getHours() > 22) {
    // It's night! Show your button!
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};

if (!checkForNight()) {
  var checkForNightIntervalID = setInterval(function() {
    if (checkForNight()) {
      clearInterval(checkForNightIntervalID);
    }
  }, 60000 /* check once per minute */);
}
```

**Edit** for better clarity.

Comment: So if you show up one minute before you need to wait an hour?

Comment: No. Read the last bit.

Comment: I did, but your code still would have to wait an hour after you called it on page load.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the comment. Maybe I should edit for clarity. When I said "you'll end up breaking it into a couple of methods" I meant - 1 method for the interval, 1 for the check... etc. I'll re-word it for better clarity.

Comment: So you have one method for check. You come in one minute beforehand. It is not valid until the minute is up. You say, nope it is not time. So you set the code to check the next hour to see if it is time. Than it will change. Code needs to be adjusted to run on the hour, not an hour from when the user hits the page.

Comment: I understand what you're saying now, but I also think you're being too nitpicky. OP asked for a general approach to this, which I provided. I believe OP can make his own educated decision about what the proper interval to use is.

Comment: To avoid unnecessary debate, and because this check is mega-lightweight, I edited the example to use a once-per-minute check.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the "when needed" part is meaning "when the scope change".

So I propose using a filter like so:

**HTML**

```
<button ng-show="someDate | isNight">Visible at night</button>
```

or

```
<button ng-show="someDate | isNight:19:5">Visible at night</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('yourApp', [])
.filter('isNight', IsNightFilter);

IsNightFilter.$inject = ['$filter'];

function IsNightFilter($filter) {
    return function (now, startNight, endNight) {
        if (now) {
            if (typeof now.getMonth !== 'function') {
                now = new Date(now);
            }

            var hours = now.getHours();

            startNight = startNight || 22;
            endNight = endNight || 6;

            if (hours < endNight || hours > startNight) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    };
}
```